# Can I setup this contexual filter in a better way?

Tags: 7, views

I have a 2 content type:
 - Organization
 - Department (the Departement have an entity reference to an Organization)
and the user have entity reference to an Organization too.

I want to build a view that show me the department of the Organization of the logged used.
I add a php contexual filter:

```
global $user;
$user_fields = user_load($user->uid);

return $user_fields->field_organization['und']['0']['target_id'];
```

and it works.

But i'm wondering: is this the only way to do that on Drupal 7? There is a better solution? 
I know that insert php code in db is not a good idea but how can I do this view without doing this?

Thank you

Comment: You could add a relation based on that field.

Comment: Can you give me some more information on how to setup contexual filter and relation?